# PySpark: Split a df frame n times

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking for a way to split a spark dataframe n times like  you can do with pythons string split method.

I have a log files each  file with 11million+ lines. I need to split the df 3 times exactly on a " " (space) as I have other data with spaces that I need, so using dataframe split creates a mess ; request.useragent is what messes up the split.

```
2017-09-24T00:17:01+00:00 dev-lb01 proxy[49]: {"backend_connect_time_ms":0,"request.useragent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; ASUS_Z00VD Build\/LMY47I; wv) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version\/4.0 Chrome\/43.0.235","resp.code":304,"retries_count":0,"session_duration_ms":979,"srv_conn_count":31,"srv_queue_count":0,"termination_state":"--","timestamp":1506212220}
```

Wanted output

```
date                        host       app         json
2017-09-24T00:17:01+00:00 | dev-lb01 | proxy[49]: | {"backend_connect_time_ms":0,"request.useragent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; ASUS_Z00VD Build\/LMY47I; wv) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version\/4.0 Chrome\/43.0.235","resp.code":304,"retries_count":0,"session_duration_ms":979,"srv_conn_count":31,"srv_queue_count":0,"termination_state":"--","timestamp":1506212220}
```

I've considered turning into a Pandas DF but memory consumption is going to be an issue. I trying to avoid have to rdd.map.collect() and then using python string method to split and turning back into a dataframe as its a ton of overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by splitting on `\\s(?![^\\{]*\\})` instead of simply on space. For example:

```
split_col = pyspark.sql.functions.split(df['my_str_col'], '\\s(?![^\\{]*\\})')
df = df.withColumn('date', split_col.getItem(0))
  .withColumn('host', split_col.getItem(1))
  .withColumn('app', split_col.getItem(2))
  .withColumn('json', split_col.getItem(3))
```